# Changed server account and php scripts no longer work

Tags: php

I inherited a website that recently changed hosting accounts. Both were on virtual servers. On the new account several of the php scripts have stopped working. They were working before the change.

I've already tried changing register_globals and that didn't work.

What other types of settings can I try changing? Things that might stop scripts from working on a different server.

I know this is generic, but I just need some ideas of where to start to troubleshoot the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you made sure database credentials are accurate? File paths up to date?

Comment: have the Document roots changed? Have you checked permissions on the files? Can you access HTML/CSS Files via the web server?

Comment: There are lots of potential issues: PHP versions, what compilation options were enabled, and what php.ini settings are, what the document-root is, what the file-permissions are on various folders, etc. Try printing out phpinfo() pages on each server if you have access to the original server... but in any case, make sure that display_errors in enabled and configured correctly and let us know what the error message is.

Comment: Post some specific errors? That'll help a bunch.

Comment: Database credentials are fine. The weird thing is, it's just a couple of the queries that aren't working. And one javascript script  isn't working either. 

What is the best way to log errors? I'm not sure if I'm getting any errors at all.

Comment: And I don't have access to the old server anymore. I wish I did.

Comment: If it helps, the main thing that seems to have stopped working involves query stings like: http://www.domain.com/search.php?Search=FirstThing&Type=V"

Comment: Ok, I looked at the old host's FAQ and it looks like there were running 5.3.

What changed would need to be made in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of `php` that the new server is running by echoing `phpinfo()`. That sometimes tends be the case, if you are not missing other things such as file paths and others.

Comment: Not sure what the old one was. The new one is running 5.2.16

Comment: Ok, I looked at the old host's FAQ and it looks like there arerunning 5.3. The current host is running 5.2. What changed would need to be made?

Comment: Ok, sorry. 

I was told all the code was working on the old server and apparently it wasn't.

There was a line of code that was overriding all search results with a default. Took out that line and everything is working.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time. The good news is, I did learn some stuff from your comments. And that's always a good thing!

Thanks again. And Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy new year to you too! :)